# What is the "SystemTracker" in the Azure Service Bus Exception?

Tags: azure, azureservicebus

I am getting the below exception and would like to know what is the "SystemTracker" that is mentioned in the exception. Also, the namespace in the message entity and in the System Tracker are different. Why could those be different? One has "stage1c" and the other is "1a". If 1c is a failover for "1a", then could it log exception like this?

```
Azure.Messaging.ServiceBus.ServiceBusException: Put token failed. status-code: 404, status-description: The messaging entity 'sb://c0000hwabt-stage1c.servicebus.windows.net/becm.job.summary.response' could not be found. To know more visit https://aka.ms/sbResourceMgrExceptions.  TrackingId:3123b33a-315a-40d5-a1e7-243b2611335e_G9, SystemTracker:c0000hwabt-stage1a.servicebus.windows.net:becm.job.summary.response, Timestamp:2022-10-20T15:56:04. (MessagingEntityNotFound)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These are set by the Service Bus service for use with correlating logs and troubleshooting from the service-side.  They're helpful information to include when opening a support ticket but are otherwise not useful.  Your application should treat them as opaque values and not assume any meaning to the client.

Comment: Thanks. Any reason why the namespace in the first phrase and the namespace in the systemtracker both differ?

Comment: I have no more insight into that than you; it's a service detail that isn't publicly documented.   Were I to speculate, I'd guess that it has something to do with identifying the node where the operation was run.